# How can I implement Presets savings in Tableview

Tags: ios, swift

I need help I have these ColorSlider App that change the color of Square with 3 sliders RGB .I like to create a Tableview where i can store presets of color and retrieve from preset name e.g. Ocean Blue,
Emerald Green, Red Ferrary etc. I create The Tableview with the push of the button but I am stuck with the rest of implementation. Please I need help.

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var redSlider: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var greenSlider: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var blueSlider: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var displaylbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var displayView: UIView!

var color:Color!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    color = Color(red: redSlider.value, green: greenSlider.value, blue: blueSlider.value)
    displaylbl.text = color.getString()
    displayView.backgroundColor = color.getColor()
}

@IBAction func sliderChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
    if (sender.tag == 1){
        color.setRed(red: sender.value)
        displaylbl.text = color.getString()
        displayView.backgroundColor = color.getColor()
    }
    else if (sender.tag == 2) {
        color.setGreen(green: sender.value)
        displaylbl.text = color.getString()
        displayView.backgroundColor = color.getColor()
    }
    else if (sender.tag == 3) {
        color.setBlue(blue: sender.value)
        displaylbl.text = color.getString()
        displayView.backgroundColor = color.getColor()
    }
}
```

}

import UIKit

class Color {
    private var red:CGFloat
    private var green:CGFloat
    private var blue:CGFloat

```
init(red:Float, green:Float, blue:Float) {
    self.red = CGFloat(red)
    self.green = CGFloat(green)
    self.blue = CGFloat(blue)
}

func setRed(red:Float) {
    self.red = CGFloat(red)
}
func setGreen(green:Float) {
    self.green = CGFloat(green)
}
func setBlue(blue:Float) {
    self.blue = CGFloat(blue)
}

func getColor() -> UIColor {
    let color = UIColor(red: red/255, green: green/255, blue: blue/255, alpha: 1.0)

    return color
}
func getString() -> String {
    let string = "Red: \(Int(round(red)))\nGreen: \(Int(round(green)))\nBlue: \(Int(round(blue)))"
    return string
}
```

}

Comment: Can you please explain it more cause i didn't get what you want to ask. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Thanks Muzareen. in the MainView I have 3 sliders R.G.B. the value of sliders create a color inside the Square, if I see a color, I like to save a color in a presets of color in a tableView eg. Ocean Blue or Red Ferrary or some like that ,So when I click on the cell the Square change the color according to the name of the color . If you can give me some clue how to start i would be appreciated. Ps.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the RGB color from slider and show in box, if you have done this part then now you need to do is whenever you are showing color in box you just make a dictionary with keys like :

```
let dict = [ colorName : "whatever you want",
             colorCode : "Which you get from slider"
           ]
```

Add it in array too like:

```
arrayColor.append(dic)
```

Populate your tableview from arrayColor array, and in didselectatindexpath you need to get colorCode atIndexPath.row and set in box.

Hope this will help you. For any other query comment below.

Comment: Thanks Munzareen this is a good start point! I going to start working on these right away I will keep you post it

Comment: I'm Sorry bother you again but what do you mean with " in didselectatindexpath you need to get colorCode atIndexPath.row and set in box." Can you write some sample code? I would appreciate

Comment: In tableView didselect you will get the array row on the specific indexPath.row so you just need to get that row and parse in nsdictionary to get the colorCode which you have set while adding in array.